# Migrate the Databse from Sqlite3 to PostgreSQL

Tags: django

I want to change the databse of my django application from default(sqlit3) to PostgreSQL for better productivity
I have Mayan EDMS App which is designed in Django and used SQLite3 as the database in the back-ends and i want to change the database of my Django app from SQLite3 to PostgreSQL

Please help to to acheive this functionality

i have tried by changing the databse details

and i expect to achevie that functionality

Comment: Do you also need to migrate some (production?) data from an SQLite database to a Postgres database?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have installed postgresql in your system go ahead and create your database and remember the details as you will use them in the next steps:

Then ensure that you have installed `psycopg2-binary` in your virtual environment so do `pip install psycopg2-binary`.

Once you have that then change your db configs in `settings.py` like below:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',#change engine to this
    'NAME': 'YOUR_DB_NAME', #db name you created above
    'USER': 'YOUR_DB_USER', #db user you created above or postgres default
    'PASSWORD':'YOUR_DB_PASSWORD', #db password you created above or postgres
    'HOST': 'YOUR_DB_HOST', # usually localhost
    'PORT': 'YOUR_DB_PORT', # usually 5432
}}
```

Now you can run `python manage.py migrate` to apply your already existing migrations.

Comment: Also, if deploying to production, [consider using](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#psycopg-vs-psycopg-binary) the package `psycopg2` instead of `psycopg2-binary`.